# How to publish new from umbraco blog to umbraco web site?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-blog

Hi i have a web site on umbraco 4 CMS.Also i want to install a blog plugin.

Is there possible pull news from blog into my site.

Example i want to publish news/post everyday from blog and create link to blog page from my web site.

Preview :

[image: web site]

thx for ur help

Comment: Hi, I need some more information in order to help.
The blog and the site are in different domains?
Do you want to publish the posts manually or just to have them on your homepage automatically?

Comment: no its umbraco plugin and same domain.i want to use this http://blog4umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/42119#ReviewsAnchor

Comment: I write my blog manually but i want to publish it automatically of course

Comment: I meant to ask if you want to select the posts which are displayed in your homepage manually, or you want a macro to do it? (for example a macro that will select the 5 newest posts)

Comment: i just started to umbraco sorry.I want to macro to do it.

Comment: if so, you just have to create an xslt macro that will take and display the first 5 posts for example... I suggest you read some basic tutorials about xslt files and their use in umbraco. You must be familiar with xslt and umbraco xslt macros if you want to create a site in umbraco 4. Just for you to know: there is no support for xslt in umbraco 5 (razor is the replacement, you can start using umbraco with razor in version 4.5)

Comment: first thx for your comments.let me ask a question.i will watch xslt macro tutorials but how it works this macro ? i mean, this macro will connect database and pull first 5 posts from my blog, or using an api ? Have you any example ? thx again

Comment: You have to know more about umbraco before you go on.
Umbraco xslt macros do not refer to the db, they take the information from the xml file...
I'm telling you again: start reading about xslt and umbraco - don't try to make shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work if you are using Blog4Umbraco.  It requires that you have the source as a ContentPicker parameter and the maxItems as a number.  It does some things like format the date for sorting properly and checking for posts in the past (in case they are scheduled).

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:variable name="documentTypeAlias" select="string('BlogPost')"/>
<xsl:variable name="source" select="/macro/source"/>
<xsl:variable name="maxItems" select="/macro/maxItems" />


<xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="currPosts" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById($source)//BlogPost [@isDoc and umbraco.library:DateDiff(@createDate, umbraco.library:CurrentDate(), 'm') &lt; 0]"/>


  <xsl:for-each select="$currPosts">
    <xsl:sort select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime(@createDate, 'yyyyMMdd')" data-type="number" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $maxItems">
      <div>

        <h4><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></h4>
        <span class="homeBlogDate"><xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:FormatDateTime(@createDate, 'M.dd.yy')"/></span>
        <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:TruncateString(umbraco.library:StripHtml(bodyText), 140, ' ')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>...
        </p>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}" class="postReadMore">
          read more &gt;
        </a>
      </div>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>



</xsl:template>
```